# Bootstrap breaking to a new line at md breakpoint

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

If the following html forces the next columns to break to new line at md breakpoint and up

```
<div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block"></div>
```

How would I modify it to do the opposite - force to break to a new line at md and below?

Answer (score -1):

just exchange the "block" and "none" part
like